# ThreeJS update shadow for buffergeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I have a model .gltf loaded in ThreeJS with a keyframe animation that change the shape of the object ( it's a point level animation ). It's working fine, but the shadow doesn't change!
I played around with `geometry.computeVertexNormals()`, but when I apply that, my model turns total black.

Can someone help me with this one?

Thanks,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to call `BufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals()`. You can enable shadow casting by doing this:

```js
gltf.scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) {

        object.castShadow = true;

    }

}
```

If the model should also receive shadows, set the property `receiveShadows` to `true`, too.

You also need to enable shadows on the renderer, properly configure the shadow camera of your light and ensure that the floor has a material that can receive shadows (e.g. not `MeshBasicMaterial`). An example like the following might be a good orientation:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_blending

Comment: Actually my object already cast shadows, it just doesn't update when the shape change: if I export the model with the last keyframe (the deformed object) the shadows are different, that means that it works just on init...I can provide some screens if it helps...

Comment: Would it also possible for you to share a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/hyok6tvj/)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I'm in Australia right now, with a different timezone.
I worked on two jsfiddle: that is not my model, but the animation is very similar.

The first example show the shadows changing on vertex change ( you can also try changing the position of the light )

https://jsfiddle.net/fw5y309n/1/

The second one, it's what happen to my model ( I removed this line of code sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals(); )

https://jsfiddle.net/f8qo1Lnc/

But if I add the computeVertexNormals to my geometry, my model turns completely black! Do you know why?

Comment: I haven't mentioned that, maybe can help: I'm working with a BufferGeometry, while in the fiddle I provided is a SphereGeometry. Does it make a lot of difference?